# Unique ids in database

Tags: mysql, database, nosql

I'm often seeing sites there IDs in urls looks like this:
`http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/forum/view/2811510711334022807/`
How do they achieve this? This isn't regular autoincrement field. All ids seems to be random, but at fixed width. What are the benefits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to hide the real id (which is auto_increment) in a big random-looking number. For example:

- the first digit shows where the real Id starts
- the second digit shows the length
- the real id is located as determined by the previous two points
- everything else is random numbers up to a predefined length

Other options are:

- [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) - your example doesn't seem to use one, but it is universally unique identifier and is sometimes used.
- [snowflake](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/06/announcing-snowflake.html) - twitter's new id generation method (or something like it)

Note that there are two important aspects here:

- don't let users easily guess IDs - this is handled by my example. But if there are protected resources, always protect them with a security check in addition to the unguessable ID
- provide cluster-wide unique ids - UUIDs, snowflake, and the likes, guarantee that an ID is unique across a cluster of machines.

Answer (score 0):

GUIDs/UUIDs such as this make it much harder to guess what will and won't be a valid ID number. Unless you have 10^18 users, the valid IDs will be very sparse compared to invalid ones.